# tmutil - Failed to delete local snapshot

Tags: mac, startup, apfs

My mbp is stuck on boot and fsck cannot be performed because of:

```
snap_metadata_val object (oid <aléatoire>): invalid extentref_tree_oid (0x0)
```

It happens that I have dataless snapshot and if I try to:

```
tmutil deletelocalsnapshots <date>
```

I'm getting:

```
Failed to delete local snapshot '<date>'
```

Comment: I wish I could help, but all I can do is point to a similar tale of woe, as yet unresolved - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328358/recurring-volume-damage-time-machine-issues [see all the links too, they're part of the overall problem]. I think my next step will be to eliminate APFS entirely & see how it goes back on HFS+.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue when trying to delete the local snapshot from the Terminal offered by my Mac. The thing is that it booted in "installer" mode and I had to `chroot /Volumes/Macintosh HD` to be able to run the `tmutil` commands. The delete however didn't work in this installer mode.

So I had to restart the computer holding Shift to start in safe mode. From there, I could start a Terminal and run the above commands to delete the empty snapshot.

Comment: This worked for me. The bottom line is "Boot in safe mode by holding down shift key and then use the `tmutil deletelocalsnapshots` command to get rid of un-deletable snapshots".

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question but you should run

```
tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

if one says `(dataless)`, you can delete it, as advised [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8092082)

Check `man tmutil` of course too.

should be in form YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS as stated at that link.

It worked for me when I was in this situation.

I did not need sudo to do this.