# Mac producing corrupt "dataless" local snapshots

Tags: time-machine, sleep-wake, apfs

On my MacBook Pro running 10.13.6 and formatted with APFS, I'm periodically seeing an issue where the machine is frozen when I try to wake it up, and requires a hard reboot to use again.

After some research, I found that corrupt "dataless" local snapshots can cause issues with sleep/wake. When investigating using

```
> tmutil listlocalsnapshots
```

I am seeing things like

```
> MacBook-Pro:~ myaccount$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-08-02-172540 (dataless)
com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-08-04-092555
```

So I've been deleting them successfully like this

```
> sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2018-08-02-172540
```

...and that will fix the problem for a while. But inevitably a few weeks later, I see the same issue again: frozen machine, hard restart, dataless local snapshot.

How do I stop my machine from producing corrupted local snapshots in the first place? Is this an issue with APFS?

Comment: It's a combination of APFS & High Sierra. Reformatting to HFS+ fixes it, as does upgrading to the Mojave beta - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328358/recurring-volume-damage-time-machine-issues

Comment: Update: this is still happening under 10.14.3. I still very frequently see these come up.

Comment: Do you run any kind of Antivirus? I suspected BitDefender of really messing up Time Machine.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that. It's a fairly vanilla install of Mojave, and I even did a clean install when I first upgraded. I'm running Mojave on another Mac and the snapshots are consistently coming up clean (in other words, none of them are "dataless"). I'm not seeing it freeze as hard as it was under High Sierra, though.

Comment: OK, then I can't help. Wish you luck.